# Why are my split equations aligned to right by default?

Tags: equations, alignment, split

My tex environments include below

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cases}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=500
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{bm}
```

Two equations appear to be aligned to right by default.

The 1st is like below, I want the *otherwise* to be aligned to center with the upper condition.

```
\begin{equation}
p^\mathrm{H}_l=\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&p^\mathrm{H}_l,&k\in S^\mathrm{AL}_l\;\mathrm{and}\;t^\mathrm{E}_l=1\\
&0,             &\mathrm{otherwise}
\end{aligned}
\right..
\end{equation}
```

[image]

The 2nd is like below, I want the "*σ*=" to be aligned to left.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sigma^\alpha_l=\\
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&2|P_{uv}|,|Y_{uv}^{-1}-2Z_{uv}+Z_{uu}+Z_{vv}|<\varepsilon\\
&0,|Y_{uv}^{-1}-2Z_{uv}+Z_{uu}+Z_{vv}|\geq\varepsilon
\end{aligned}
\right.,l=\lbrace{u,v}\rbrace,
\end{split}
\label{equ:REI1}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Can any parameters correct the splitted equations to center alignment? Or did I missed any environment at the beginning of my tex?

Comment: Nice start! Could you please [post a MWE,](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) rather than a snippet of text and then an image of part of the preamble? Figuring out which packages cause this to happen and which are unrelated would be a good first step to solving the problem as well.

Comment: You are missing the `&`'s plus you might want to look up the cases env, no need to do that by hand

Comment: @daleif & cannot help align the sigma to left side.

Comment: The left side of what? You're breaking the line. Alignment columns are split into two parts, left and right of the &. The leg part is right aligned and the right side is left aligned. You have no &, thus there is only one part of the alignment column, the left side, thus all is right aligned. Perhaps you should start over and start by explaining what you are trying to do. And importantly, please don't post image of source code. No one want to type in your code on order to try it out.

Comment: Please clarify the purpose of "note2": is it maybe supposed to occur on a separate line? Please advise.

Comment: @deleif Thank you for your advice, and sorry to causing the trouble in understanding. I have corrected my descriptions as you suggested, please check.

Comment: Off-topic: Please don't write `\lbrace{u,v}\rbrace`. Instead, write either `\lbrace u,v\rbrace` or `\{u,v\}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the desired centering by using `array`; however, this doesn't seem the best way to lay out the equation.

For the second equation, I'm not seeing why using *l* instead of {*u*,*v*}:

```latex
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
%\usepackage{cite} % is it compatible with IEEEtran?
\usepackage{graphicx} % no pdftex option
%\usepackage{epstopdf} % not required
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
%\usepackage{fixltx2e} % does nothing in recent versions of LaTeX
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % also math is in Times font

%\interdisplaylinepenalty=500 % if you use it, place it after loading packages

\begin{document}

This is how you'd prefer
\begin{equation}
p^{\mathrm{H}}_l=\left\{
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% like cases does
  \begin{array}{@{} l @{\quad} c @{}}
  p^{\mathrm{H}}_l, & k\in S^{\mathrm{AL}}_l \text{ and } t^{\mathrm{E}}_l=1 \\
  0,                & \text{otherwise}
  \end{array}
\right..
\end{equation}
but in my opinion this has some defects: centering doesn't help in
locating the boundary of the top condition; punctuation is inconsistent,
particularly in the period hanging from nothing.
\begin{equation}
p^{\mathrm{H}}_l=
  \begin{cases}
  p^{\mathrm{H}}_l, & k\in S^{\mathrm{AL}}_l \text{ and } t^{\mathrm{E}}_l=1, \\
  0,                & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
The second equation should be
\begin{equation}\label{equ:REI1}
\sigma^\alpha_{\{u,v\}}=
  \begin{cases}
  2|P_{uv}|, & |Y_{uv}^{-1}-2Z_{uv}+Z_{uu}+Z_{vv}|<\varepsilon,\\
  0,         & |Y_{uv}^{-1}-2Z_{uv}+Z_{uu}+Z_{vv}|\geq\varepsilon,
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I added some comments to the code, please have a look at them. I also add that the syntax

```latex
a^{\mathrm{b}}
```

should be preferred to `a^\mathrm{b}`.

[image]

Comment: wow, really amazing

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking to achieve the following result?

[image]

I must confess to having no idea what "note2" is supposed to represent in the structure of the equation.

If you inspect the code below, you will notice that I replaced the `\left\{` and `\right.` instructions and the `aligned` environment with a single `cases` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'cases' env.
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \sigma^{\alpha}_l=
  \begin{cases}
     equation1,\\
     equation2
  \end{cases}
  note2
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* with some formatting adjustments for one of the new equations.

Here's how I would input the second equation; note the use of a `cases` environment and of the `\text` macro.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'cases' env. and'\text' macro
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
p^\mathrm{H}_l=
\begin{cases}
p^{\mathrm{H}}_l & \text{if $k\in S^{\mathrm{AL}}_l$ and $t^{\mathrm{E}}_l=1$;}\\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

---

*Second addendum*: For the second expression, I would again use a `cases` environment. In addition, I would write `otherwise` in the second row rather than provide a long equation, and I would take the term `For $l\in\lbrace u,v\rbrace$` entirely out of the displayed equation. (Moreover, I would use `\in` rather than `=`...)

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
For $l\in\lbrace u,v\rbrace$, 
\begin{equation} \label{equ:REI1}
\sigma^\alpha_l=
\begin{cases}
2|P_{uv}|&\text{if $|Y_{uv}^{-1}-2Z_{uv}+Z_{uu}+Z_{vv}|<\varepsilon$;}\\
0        &\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Mico! I have updated my descriptions, please check. The "note2" corresponds to the global condition in the second equation in my updated question.

Comment: @L.Li - Please see the addendum to my earlier answer; I've tried to address one of your follow-up questions.

Comment: thank you, I replaced the \begin{aligned} by \begin{cases} to solve the problem! How about my 2nd question?

Comment: @L.Li - Please see the second addendum I just posted.

Comment: I got you, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I would write your equation as follows:

```
\documentclass[jornal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, bm, mathtools} % math env.
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\usepackage{cases}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=50

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{equation}
\sigma^\alpha_l=
\begin{cases}
2\abs*{P_{uv}}, & \mathit{condition}(uv)<\varepsilon  \\
0,              & \mathit{condition}(uv)\geq\varepsilon
\end{cases},
l=\{u,v\},
\label{equ:REI1}
\end{equation}
where $ \mathit{condition}(uv)=\abs*{Y_{uv}^{-1}-2Z_{uv}+Z_{uu}+Z_{vv}}$.

\smallskip
\lipsum[2-8]
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]